# Creating a Function - Excel VBA

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I have some code that makes a HTTP request and fetches an XML from an API before parsing.

The HTTP request part of my code is always the same and the only parameter that changes is the URL I send the request to. I'm wondering if I can therefore convert the request to a Function?

```vb
Set xmldoc = CreateObject("Msxml.DOMDocument")
Set httpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")
xmldoc.async = False

httpReq.Open "GET", myUrl, False

httpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    If Sheet2.proxyStatus = "ON" Then
    httpReq.setProxy 2, Sheet2.proxyServer, ""
    ElseIf Sheet2.proxyStatus = "OFF" Then
    httpReq.setProxy 0, "", ""
    End If
httpReq.setTimeouts -1, -1, -1, -1
httpReq.send request

xmldoc.LoadXML httpReq.responseText

Set xmlElement = xmldoc.DocumentElement
```

After making the request I use some code like this to parse data from the XML:

```vb
TotalSessions = xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("//Row[@rowKey='Sessions']/Value[@columnId='SESSIONS']").Text
```

The code that parses the information can't be included in the function because the nodes that it is looking for and the variables it is assigning are unique and numerous but it needs to be able to read the XML downloaded by the Function obviously.

I have tried creating the Function but I am unsure what type to define it as, so I went with Object:

```vb
Function fetchXML(url As String) As Object

Set xmldoc = CreateObject("Msxml.DOMDocument")
Set httpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttprequest.5.1")
xmldoc.async = False

httpReq.Open "GET", url, False

httpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    If Sheet2.proxyStatus = "ON" Then
    httpReq.setProxy 2, Sheet2.proxyServer, ""
    ElseIf Sheet2.proxyStatus = "OFF" Then
    httpReq.setProxy 0, "", ""
    End If
httpReq.setTimeouts -1, -1, -1, -1
httpReq.send request

xmldoc.LoadXML httpReq.responseText

Set xmlElement = xmldoc.DocumentElement

End Function
```

I have then tried to call the Function and Parse some information:

```vb
fetchXML (coukChannels30DayUrl)

coukPPCSessionsSS = xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("//Row[@rowKey='1#11588418521354:1158842490346']/Value[@columnId='SESSIONS']").Text
```

But unfortunately it didn't work, am I calling the function wrong? Is it the wrong type? Can I even do this? lol

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Okay I got it to work, I just needed to change this line in the function:

```
Set xmlElement = xmldoc.DocumentElement
```

To this:

```
Set fetchXML = xmldoc.DocumentElement
```

And then change this line in the sub:

```
fetchXML (coukChannels30DayUrl)
```

To this:

```
Set xmlElement = fetchXML(coukChannels30DayUrl)
```

And it's working very nicely, yay for functions.